# jQuery: Fire mousemove events less often

Tags: jquery, settimeout, mousemove

I'm trying to figure out a clean way to aggregate mousemove events so that I ensure my code gets called, but only once every 250-300 milliseconds.

I've thought about using something like the following, but was wondering if there was a better pattern, or something jQuery provides that will do the same thing:

```
var mousemove_timeout = null;

$('body').mousemove(function() {
  if (mousemove_timeout == null) {
    mousemove_timeout = window.setTimeout(myFunction, 250);
  }
});

function myFunction() {
  /*
   * Run my code...
   */

  mousemove_timeout = null;
}
```

**EDIT:** The accepted answer below would work perfectly for this situation, however, I found that the `mousestop()` functionality provided in the answer actually eliminated my need for the aggregation, so if you're reading this question and looking for an answer, see if the [mousestop](http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/posts/view/jquery-mousestop-event) plugin is what you really need!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine except that you should [clear the timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.clearTimeout) before setting it to null or it might leak:

```
window.clearTimeout(mousemove_timeout);
mousemove_timeout = null;
```

As an alternative you could use mousemove/[mousestop](http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/posts/view/jquery-mousestop-event) in conjunction with [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)

```
var timer = null;
var isIntervalSet = false;

$('body').mousemove(function() {
    if (isIntervalSet) {
        return;
    }
    timer = window.setInterval(function() {
        /*
        * Run my code...
        */    
    }, 250);
    isIntervalSet = true;
}).mousestop(function() {
    isIntervalSet = false;
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
});
```

Comment: +1 - Thanks for the tip! Is this the best/cleanest way though? Seems like a bit of a hack...

Comment: Yes indeed it is a bit of a hack, `window.setInterval` would be more adapted to this scenario.

Comment: Accepted! - Turns out, the `mousestop` function is exactly what I need and will eliminate the timeout code entirely. Thanks so much!

Comment: Something's not right with this approach: if the mouse keep moving constantly, mousemove event keep getting fired, but the mouse coordinates remain the same.

Answer (score 20):

After I tried the solution in the accepted answer, I found out that if the mouse keep moving constantly, especially in circular motion, mousemove() event is fired continuously, but the mouse coordinates remain the same.
So I came up with a simpler solution which eliminates mousestop() and setTimeout.

```
$("body").mousemove(function (e) {
        if (enableHandler) {
            handleMouseMove(e);
            enableHandler = false;
        }
});

timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    enableHandler = true;
}, 100);
```

This will correctly call handleMouseMove() approximately every 100ms. (Note that I said approximately because time delays and intervals in JavaScript is not real-time guaranteed)

Comment: +1 - Thanks! This is actually the type of solution that I was looking for originally. This is a much cleaner approach than the accepted answer, but, the mousestop plugin is still what I went with.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the timer when mouse is not moving?

Answer (score 4):

A solution and a question^^

What about this approach without a global var. Is that a suitable solution?

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").mousemove((function() {
        var timer = null;

        return function() {
            if (timer !== null) {
                window.clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            timer = window.setTimeout(foo, 250);
        };
    })());
});

function foo() {
    //...
}
```

Comment: +1 - I definitely like not using a global variable. Although I haven't tried this code, it does look fairly clean and intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way of gettin the mouse position in a custom period of miliseconds

```
var timer;
var refresh_time = 50;
var x = 0;
jQuery('body').mousemove(function(evt) {
  if (timer)
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      var mouse_x = evt.clientX;
      if(mouse_x != x){
        x = mouse_x;
        console.log('mouse is on a new x position' + x);    
      }
    }, refresh_time);        
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You seek code Throttling / Debouncing.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/
http://drupalmotion.com/article/debounce-and-throttle-visual-explanation

Sample from underscore.jS

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but it might be of use to people visiting this thread, here is my 2 cents.

Using the modulus operator and simple number increments, you can throttle the firing rate of your function with minimal performance hit, like so;

```
var fired = 0;
$('#element').on('mousemove', function(){
   fired++;
   // Fire 5x less than usual
   if(!(fired % 5) || fired == 1) yourFunction();
})
```

Additionally, if you're afraid to hit the max integer limit, you can reset the fired variable every X thousand hits (again, using the modulus operator) or by using the mouseout event.

Answer (score 1):

This was a really interesting question. I found a less hackish way to do this on, and you can check out this [**live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/ZxkuX/) of the following snippet:

```
({
    event: null,
    interval: null,
    init: function(){
        var self = this;
        $(document).bind("mousemove", function(e){self.event=e;});
        this.interval = setInterval(function(){
            /** do what you wish **/
            console.log(self.event);
        }, 250);
        return this;
    },
    stop: function(){
        $(document).unbind("mousemove", this.event);
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },
}).init();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save a few lines by using the timeout to null the timer:

```
var paused = null;

$("body").mousemove(function (e) {
    if (!paused){
        /** your code here **/
        paused = setTimeout(function(){paused=null}, 250);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead of timeouts?